# BigInteger: Integral Constant is too large

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, math, biginteger

I want to split a BigInteger Value (111111222222333333444444555555) into an array of 5 elements (basically splitting a large number into different coins). They are split by counting backwards and SubStringing each 6 numbers. I'm building this for a unity game.
That means, the test array after running the function should be an array of {111111,222222,333333,444444,555555}.

In my test I call
`ToRegularCoins(111111222222333333444444555555, test);` where test is an int[5] array.

The function is as follows:

```
public void ToRegularCoins(BigInteger coinsValue, int[] targetArray)
{
    string coinsValueString = coinsValue.ToString();
    string[] coinsValueStringArray = new string[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            coinsValueStringArray[i] = coinsValueString.Substring(coinsValueString.Length - 6);
            coinsValueString = coinsValueString.Remove(coinsValueString.Length - 6, 6);
            Debug.Log("Index: " + i + "coinsValueString: " + coinsValueString);
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Exception in Index: " + i);
            coinsValueStringArray[i] = coinsValueString;
            coinsValueString = "";
        }
        try
        {
            targetArray[i] = int.Parse(coinsValueStringArray[i]); // Turn string into Int at Array's index
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            Debug.Log("No Coins of Index: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Running my script I get ***XY.cs(32,24): error CS1021: Integral constant is too large***

How can I fix this error? Am I maybe doing this way more complicated than I should?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable like this.

```
var coinsValue = BigInteger.Parse("111111222222333333444444555555");
```

Comment: This worked. I do not understand the difference, though. Can you elaborate the difference to my solution please?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your code closely, your first line of a  `ToRegularCoins()` function converting `BigInteger` to `string`, so instead of parsing value to `BigInteger` you can directly pass string to `ToRegularCoins()` function

```
//Replace coinValue to coinValueString.
public void ToRegularCoins(string coinsValueString, int[] targetArray)
{
   //No need to convert input parameter to string, as it is already in string format
    string[] coinsValueStringArray = new string[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            coinsValueStringArray[i] = coinsValueString.Substring(coinsValueString.Length - 6);
            coinsValueString = coinsValueString.Remove(coinsValueString.Length - 6, 6);
            Debug.Log("Index: " + i + "coinsValueString: " + coinsValueString);
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            Debug.Log("Exception in Index: " + i);
            coinsValueStringArray[i] = coinsValueString;
            coinsValueString = "";
        }
        try
        {
            targetArray[i] = int.Parse(coinsValueStringArray[i]); // Turn string into Int at Array's index
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {
            Debug.Log("No Coins of Index: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

When you are calling your method, pass `string` instead of `BigInteger`.

```
ToRegularCoins("111111222222333333444444555555", test);
```

Comment: 1) Add validate the length of string (probably must be the same)
2) Add validate string contains the only number (you can not have to)
 - then you can remove FormatExceptions add your Exception earlier

Comment: Agreed @RafalT, but this will change OP's current implementation. I just tried so solve his/her problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As I'm working with BigInts in my program, changing the BigInt to a String is not an option for me.

Comment: If this is the case, then parse it before passing it to your `ToRegularCoins()` Check @vivaknuna's answer, regarding parsing string to bigint